# Initialize variable based on enum

Tags: rust, enums

I have an enum:

```
enum DaEnum{
    One(u8),
    Strang(String),
}
```

I would like to variable `y` to be assigned value from enum:

```
let x = DaEnum::One(1);
let y;
match x{
    DaEnum::One(one) => {y = one},
    DaEnum::Strang(strang) => {y = strang},
}
println!("Value of y =>{:?}",y);
```

Here is the error from `cargo run`:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src\main.rs:33:40
   |
30 |     let y;
   |         - expected due to the type of this binding
...
33 |         DaEnum::Strang(strang) => {y = strang},
   |                                        ^^^^^^ expected `u8`, found struct `String`
```

Desired case would be when `x` is `1`, `y` is `1`and when `x` is a `String`, `y` would also be a `String`.

Comment: You cannot do that. Variables cannot have a dynamic type. But this sounds like a XY problem.

Comment: I have multiple things to do with `y` regardless of what type it is. Would be there a better way instead of repeating all the code in each match arm ?

Comment: What thing can you do with something that you don't know its type? Perhaps you're looking for `dyn Trait`?

Comment: For example, if enum is Fruit and variants are Apple and Banana, they both have peel(). I am looking to not repeat peel() in both match arms, would rather call it just once after/outside the match scope. Thank you for the `dyn Trait` suggestion, will look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generic function may help with your case if it's simple enough. You can pick up all the common behavior into one function and invoke it in every match arm. Please be aware of the trait because it must be shared by all your usages.

```rust
#[derive(Clone)]
enum DaEnum {
    One(u8),
    Strang(String),
}

fn main() {
    let x = DaEnum::One(1);

    fn common_stuff<T: std::fmt::Debug>(v: T) {
        // common stuff
        println!("Value of y =>{:?}", v);
    }

    // (1)
    match x.clone() {
        DaEnum::One(one) => {
            let y = one;
            // not common stuff
            common_stuff(y);
        }
        DaEnum::Strang(strang) => {
            let y = strang;
            // not common stuff
            common_stuff(y);
        }
    }

    // (2)
    match x {
        DaEnum::One(one) => common_stuff(one),
        DaEnum::Strang(strang) => common_stuff(strang),
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your time and effort @tieway59, (2) has helped me achieve what I was going for in this particular case.